# Keeping youtube controls always visible in HTML5 iframe [autohide=0 depreciated]

Tags: html, youtube-api

I would like to keep youtube controls always visible, even when the user don't hover the mouse over the iframe.
With the latest version of youtube-api, I can't use the option autohide=0 anymore since it's depreciated for HTML5. Is there any other method that may arrive at the same result ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could hide the built-in controls entirely, then write your own controls to control the video?

Comment: Maybe you could programmatically trigger a mouse over event on the video repeatedly so that it keeps showing the controls.

Comment: Thanks ! I was hoping there was still a solution within the youtube iframe options. But yeah I can always cheat with javascript ... ugly : ( .

Comment: in case anyone is looking for this again i got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586000/keep-youtube-controls-always-visible/65586795#65586795